# Magium for selenium tesing not working with magento2.2

Tags: magento2, testing, selenium

```
 composer require magium/magento
You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug
Using version ^0.6.11 for magium/magento
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - magium/magium 1.1.9 requires phpunit/phpunit ~5.7 -> no matching package found.
    - magium/magium 1.1.8 requires phpunit/phpunit ~5.7 -> no matching package found.
    - magium/magium 1.1.7 requires phpunit/phpunit ~5.7 -> no matching package found.
    - magium/magium 1.1.6 requires phpunit/phpunit ~5.7 -> no matching package found.
    - magium/magium 1.1.5 requires phpunit/phpunit ~5.7 -> no matching package found.
    - magium/magium 1.1.4 requires phpunit/phpunit ~5.7 -> no matching package found.
    - magium/magium 1.1.3 requires phpunit/phpunit ~5.7 -> no matching package found.
    - magium/magium 1.1.2 requires phpunit/phpunit ~5.7 -> no matching package found.
    - magium/magium 1.1.10 requires phpunit/phpunit ~5.7 -> no matching package found.
    - magium/magium 1.1.1 requires phpunit/phpunit ~5.7 -> no matching package found.
    - magium/magium 1.1.0 requires phpunit/phpunit ~5.7 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for magium/magento ^0.6.11 -> satisfiable by magium/magento[0.6.11].
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/console v2.8.28
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v2.8.28
    - magium/magento 0.6.11 requires magium/magium ~1.1 -> satisfiable by magium/magium[1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.10, 1.1.11, 1.1.12, 1.1.13, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5, 1.1.6, 1.1.7, 1.1.8, 1.1.9].
    - magium/magium 1.1.11 requires symfony/console ~3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.0.8, v3.0.9, v3.1.0, v3.1.1, v3.1.10, v3.1.2, v3.1.3, v3.1.4, v3.1.5, v3.1.6, v3.1.7, v3.1.8, v3.1.9, v3.2.0, v3.2.1, v3.2.10, v3.2.11, v3.2.12, v3.2.13, v3.2.2, v3.2.3, v3.2.4, v3.2.5, v3.2.6, v3.2.7, v3.2.8, v3.2.9, v3.3.0, v3.3.1, v3.3.10, v3.3.2, v3.3.3, v3.3.4, v3.3.5, v3.3.6, v3.3.7, v3.3.8, v3.3.9].
    - magium/magium 1.1.12 requires symfony/console ~3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.0.8, v3.0.9, v3.1.0, v3.1.1, v3.1.10, v3.1.2, v3.1.3, v3.1.4, v3.1.5, v3.1.6, v3.1.7, v3.1.8, v3.1.9, v3.2.0, v3.2.1, v3.2.10, v3.2.11, v3.2.12, v3.2.13, v3.2.2, v3.2.3, v3.2.4, v3.2.5, v3.2.6, v3.2.7, v3.2.8, v3.2.9, v3.3.0, v3.3.1, v3.3.10, v3.3.2, v3.3.3, v3.3.4, v3.3.5, v3.3.6, v3.3.7, v3.3.8, v3.3.9].
    - magium/magium 1.1.13 requires symfony/console ~3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.0.8, v3.0.9, v3.1.0, v3.1.1, v3.1.10, v3.1.2, v3.1.3, v3.1.4, v3.1.5, v3.1.6, v3.1.7, v3.1.8, v3.1.9, v3.2.0, v3.2.1, v3.2.10, v3.2.11, v3.2.12, v3.2.13, v3.2.2, v3.2.3, v3.2.4, v3.2.5, v3.2.6, v3.2.7, v3.2.8, v3.2.9, v3.3.0, v3.3.1, v3.3.10, v3.3.2, v3.3.3, v3.3.4, v3.3.5, v3.3.6, v3.3.7, v3.3.8, v3.3.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.0.0, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.0.1, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.0.2, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.0.3, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.0.4, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.0.5, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.0.6, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.0.7, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.0.8, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.0.9, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.1.0, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.1.1, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.1.10, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.1.2, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.1.3, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.1.4, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.1.5, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.1.6, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.1.7, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.1.8, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.1.9, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.2.0, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.2.1, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.2.10, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.2.11, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.2.12, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.2.13, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.2.2, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.2.3, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.2.4, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.2.5, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.2.6, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.2.7, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.2.8, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.2.9, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.3.0, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.3.1, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.3.10, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.3.2, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.3.3, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.3.4, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.3.5, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.3.6, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.3.7, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.3.8, v2.8.28].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v3.3.9, v2.8.28].
    - Installation request for symfony/console == 2.8.28.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v2.8.28].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

**phpunit --version

PHPUnit 5.7.22 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.**

Answer (score 0):

Magium needs a different PHPUnit version than Magento itself. But this is not a problem as long as you don't try to install Magium and your test suite *within Magento*, which is not necessary. Create a separate project for your Magium test suite instead.

From the docs:

> Magium tests can be managed either as a distinct project or as a composer-enabled installation of Magento
>
> [...]
>
> ### Install the example project for Magento
>
> ```
> git clone https://github.com/magium/MagiumMagentoExample
> ```

More: https://magiumlib.com/blog/how-to-start-selenium-testing-on-magento-or-succeeding-at-selenium-in-under-10-minutes/

Note that the example project is for Magento 1, I don't know if there's anything like that for Magento 2, but the only difference should be that you require `magium/magento2` instead of `magium/magento`